# ASP.NET - How to add options in dropdown at server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I want to add `options` through the server side and I have tried the below logic in ASP.NET.

```cs
List<string> vendorname_list = null;
vendorname_list = (List<string>)Session["vendornamelist"];

if (vendorname_list.Count > 0)
{
    ddlvendornames.Items.Clear();
    string vnlst = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < vendorname_list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Session["vendornameselect"] != null && Session["vendornameselect"].ToString() == vendorname_list[i])
            vnlst = "<option Selected='True' value=" + vendorname_list[i] + ">" + vendorname_list[i] + "</option>";
        else
            vnlst += "<option value=" + vendorname_list[i] + ">" + vendorname_list[i] + "</option>";
    }

    // ddlvendornames.Items.Add(vnlst);

    ddlvendornames.DataSource = vnlst; // it is not appending properly 
    ddlvendornames.DataBind();
}
```

In the `Session["vendornamelist"]`, I have added the list of values through a loop. I'm adding to the string variable and the dropdown variable (`ddlvendornames`).

Please let me know if adding dropdown values using the `<option>` tag from the server side is possible.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Sorry, it's quite long time ago for me to work with ASP.NET. Why not set the dropdownlist DataSource with `List<ListItem>` instead of adding the `<option>` element.

Comment: Hi @YongShun thanks for your comment, and based on the previous select dropdown value and strong in this `Session["vendornameselect"]` and by using `html` code I'm  selected value using `"<option Selected='True' ..` and rest values normally adding to string `<option value=" + ..` and finally appending to `ddlvendornames` dropdown.

Comment: Ya, the [`ListItem(String, String, Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-web-ui-webcontrols-listitem-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-boolean)) allows you to set the option to be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, would recommend binding the option list with [ListItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem?view=netframework-4.8.1)s instead of writing and adding the `<option>` element.

```cs
List<ListItem> vnlst = new List<ListItem>();

int? selectedIndex = null;
for (int i = 0; i < vendorname_list.Count; i++)
{
    if (Session["vendornameselect"] != null && Session["vendornameselect"].ToString() == vendorname_list[i])
    {
        selectedIndex = i;
        vnlst.Add(new ListItem(vendorname_list[i], vendorname_list[i], true));
    }
    else
    {
        vnlst.Add(new ListItem(vendorname_list[i], vendorname_list[i]));
    }
}

ddlvendornames.DataSource = vnlst;
ddlvendornames.DataTextField = "Text";
ddlvendornames.DataValueField = "Value";

if (selectedIndex.HasValue)
    ddlvendornames.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex.Value;

ddlvendornames.DataBind();
```

Comment: This logic is working fine when the page is loaded initially but after refresh the page (dropdown => autopostback=true) the page is reloading and logic is executing fine (selected value is selecting this logic (`vnlst.Add(new ListItem(vendorname_list[i], vendorname_list[i], true));` but that value is not selecting in the front end )) can you please suggest me why this is happing ?

Comment: Hmmm, it looks odd, but anyhow have you tried with [`.SelectedIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-web-ui-webcontrols-dropdownlist-selectedindex) or `.SelectedValue`? Had updated my answer.

Comment: do the loading on page load, and make sure you wrap that code inside of a if (!IsPostBack) {your load ddl  code here}. Remember, page load code runs each time, and if you run the code to load up the dropdown again, then the users selection will be lost. So, you ONLY want to load the ddl one time on the first "real" page load - not each time a post-back occurs, since doing so will over write the users selection.  Hence place such code to load up a gridview, or dll in the page load event, but inside of the if (!IsPostPost) code stub to prevent a re-load on each page post-back.

Comment: @YongShun thank for your answer post and it is working fine to me but I got this error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` at `ddlvendornames.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;` and changed to `ddlvendornames.SelectedIndex = (int)selectedIndex;` now working fine .

Comment: Apologize for that, yes `selectedIndex` is nullable int. So you have to cast to int type. Either `(int)selectedIndex` or `selectedIndex.Value`.